# re.sub not acting as I would expect, please explain what is happening here?

Tags: python, python-re

For simplification, say I have the following code:

```py
import re

line = '(5) 3:16 The footnote explaination for footnote number one here.'

# trying to match a literal open parenthesis, followed by a number,
# followed by closing parenthesis - with match.group(1) being the number.
match = re.match(r'\((\d+)\)', line)


reordered_num = 1

renumbered_line_1 = re.sub(match.group(0), '{}'.format(reordered_num), line )
renumbered_line_2 = re.sub(match.group(1), '{}'.format(reordered_num), line )
```

I expected `renumbered_line_1` to have substituted "1" in place of "(5)" in the text.

I expected `renumbered_line_2` to have substituted "1" in place of "5" in the text.

Question:
Why do are both `renumbered_line_1` and `renumbered_line_2` have exactly the same contents being:

`(1) 3:16 The footnote explaination for footnote number one here`.

Is this a bug with Python 3.9.7 running on Mac ... or is there something that I am not understanding here ?

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep  3 2021, 12:45:31)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>>
>>> line = '(5) 3:16 The footnote explaination for footnote number one here.'
>>>
>>> # trying to match a literal open parenthesis, followed by a number,
>>> # followed by closing parenthesis - with match.group(1) being the number.
>>> match = re.match(r'\((\d+)\)', line)
>>>
>>>
>>> reordered_num = 1
>>>
>>> renumbered_line_1 = re.sub(match.group(0), '{}'.format(reordered_num), line )
>>> renumbered_line_2 = re.sub(match.group(1), '{}'.format(reordered_num), line )
>>>
>>> renumbered_line_1
'(1) 3:16 The footnote explaination for footnote number one here.'
>>> renumbered_line_2
'(1) 3:16 The footnote explaination for footnote number one here.'
>>>
```

Comment: You could simplify your [mre] by losing the first match and just passing `'(5)'` and `'5'` explicitly to `re.sub`.

Comment: noted ... sorry ... (it is greatly simplified from what it was in the loop)

Comment: The first argument to `re.sub()` is a _regular expression_, so `(5)` is essentially the same as `5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `match.group(0)` and `match.group(1)` in your code are respectively `(5)` and `5`. So this is what you are doing:

```
>>> re.sub('(5)', '1', '(5) 3:16 the footnote')
'(1) 3:16 the footnote'
>>> re.sub('5', '1', '(5) 3:16 the footnote')
'(1) 3:16 the footnote'
```

The reason only the `5` is replaced in both cases is that the pattern `(5)` is the single character `5` inside a group. It matches (and captures) the single character `5` in your string, so that is what you replace.

If you wanted to replace the string `(5)` including parentheses, you could do any of the following:

- manually escape the parentheses:

  ```
  re.sub(r'\(5\)', '1', '(5) 3:16 the footnote')
  ```
- use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape the parentheses:

  ```
  re.sub(re.escape('(5)'), '1', '(5) 3:16 the footnote')
  ```
- use non-regex replace:

  ```
  '(5) 3:16 the footnote'.replace('(5)', '1')
  ```

I recommend the third option, since you do not appear to be trying to use regex functionality at that point in your code.

So it would look like this in your code:

```
renumbered_line_1 = line.replace(match.group(0), str(reordered_num))
```

Comment: so ... even though match.group(0) includes parenthesis,  i.e. "(5)" ... the parenthesis get re-interpreted again as a "group" by re.sub  - since it uses parenthesis as delimiters for a group ?   And all that even with the preceding "r" in front of the string ?  Is all that correctly stated ?

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that `re.sub()`'s first argument is a regex, not a simple string like `str.replace()`, so it's not a _bug_ for the parentheses to be interpreted as a capturing group

Comment: "even with the preceding "r" in front of the string ?"—The r was in front of `r'\((\d+)\)'`, which is a completely different string. The string coming from `match.group(0)` was simply the value `(5)`, which is interpreted as a regular expression when passed into `re.sub`.